# CSS alignment problem in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, alignment

I've been putting together a drupal Website for a personal project (coffee geek Website about the Rancilio Miss Silvia) and the css is working great in Firefox and Safari but not in IE.

In IE the alignment of the central section is totally screwed up and I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

I'm working off of the Zen theme for drupal so there's a bunch of extra tags in there to make sure it's extra confusing.

The site is: http://www.silviaschool.com

The relevant style sheet is:  http://silviaschool.com/themes/zen/zen/layout-liquid.css

Thanks for any help you can offer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem #1:

```
body { width: 20%; }
```

That's being applied via the `sidebar-left` class.

problem #2:

I'm not sure if you want a fixed-width layout or not.  When I load up the page in Chrome, it appears to have fixed-width but your stylesheet applies `width: 90%` to `#page`.  If you desire fixed width, then you'll need to specify a fixed width on `#page`.

Comment: Hey mac, make sure you mark this answer as the accepted answer - it will close the question and make it easier for other people to find answers to their questions. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I believe I've now accepted the answer and upvoted it  too :)  Cheers